# Magento Sales (special price) CMS Page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've tried several tutorials found around Google... but none of those seems to work for me.

I need to create a Sales page, for products with special prices, that acts like a normal category page, with the pagination etc. The best way, I think, is to create it as a CMS so later I can have the url like this: **myshop.com/sales** . 
But I nothing is working on 1.7.0.2

can somebody give a hand of doing this, please!?

Comment: So create one category and assign special price products to sale category

Comment: nope, already tried that.